# Regex for both newline and backslash for Replace function

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a replace function to escape some characters (both newline and backslash) from a string.

Here is my code:

```
  var str = strElement.replace(/\\/\n/g, "");
```

I am trying to use regex, so that I can add more special characters if needed. Is this a valid regex or can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you replacing newlines and backslashes with '' ? `/[\\\n]/g`

Comment: new line and backslashes with empty string

Comment: For efficiency, use `/[\\\n]+/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ending the regex early with an unescaped forward slash. You also want to use a set to match individual characters. Additionally you might want to add "\r" (carriage return) in as well as "\n" (new line).

This should work:

```
var str = strElement.replace(/[\\\n\r]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a valid regex as the slash is a delimiter and ends the regex. What you probably wanted is the pipe (`|`), which is an alternation:

```
var str = strElement.replace(/\\|\n/g, "");
```

In case you need to extend it in the future it may be helpful to use a character class to improve readability:

```
var str = strElement.replace(/[\\\nabcx]/g, "");
```

A character class matches a *single* character from it's body.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I just picked JMP answer since I used his answer. But yours worked too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The regular expression replaces both the newline characters and the backslashes in escaped html text:

`var str = strElement.replace(/\\n|\\r|\\/g, '');`